# NSOutlineView in NSPopover not readable in OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nspopover

I have a `NSPopover` containing a `NSOutlineView` (**source list**) that is displayed over a usually dark background (but it's not always dark). The `NSOutlineView` has a transparent background to blend nicely with the `NSPopover` view. This looked great in OS X 10.9 but in 10.10 the system changes the text color in the `NSOutlineView` based on the background. The result is that the text becomes completely gray and unreadable in some cases:

[image]

If I change the popover to be HUD style it is more readable:

[image]

However, in this case, it becomes problematic with lighter backgrounds (the top).

Is there any way to control the text color in the `NSOutlineView` so that the color stays the same no matter the background? I have tried setting the color of the text cell to black instead of the system colors but it does not help.

Also, can I control/remove the transparency of the `NSPopover`? I have read that `NSPopover` makes use of `NSVisualEffectView`, which has some appearance controls, but I don't know how to access it from NSPopover.

For aesthetic reasons I do not want to put the `NSOutlineView` under a solid background view. In this case there will be a ugly mismatch in color between the popover background and its arrow.

EDIT:

I was able to remove the transparency using the following code:

```
NSView *popoverView = popover.contentViewController.view.superview;
popoverView.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameAqua];
```

It works but feels like a ugly hack. I welcome better suggestions.

EDIT2:

This is what it looks like with the aqua style. No transparency and black text.

[image]

Comment: What does it look like with the appearance set to Aqua?

Answer (score 1):

Set the mode to something different other than **source list** and you should get the pre-10.10 style, i.e. without the translucency.

Comment: I used `None`. `Source List` would be okay but the group text jumps up/down on mouse over if there are no chars running under the base line (like 'g'). `Regular` is simply insane :-(